# How to hide Close Window Option in Taskbar Right click menu in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, taskbar

See the following image. I want to remove that close window option from that menu. That menu is shown when you right click on the form icon on taskbar. I need to do it in c#. Any hint or sample solution?

[image]

Comment: Yes.. I'm using that currently. but I need to remove that option as the `Form.Closing` is becoming more complex to maintain. :(

Comment: you can hide the program icon in task bar

Comment: you can hide taskbar!